# delaying UITapGestureRecognizer

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, uitapgesturerecognizer

I have a UITapGestureRecognizer which basically performs an action to add a subview. When I tap I only want the subview to load once, however when I tap twice really fast, it performs the action twice. How can I prevent this? Basically after it's tapped once I want the tap gesture recognizer to be disabled temporarily for some seconds. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Disable your tap recognizer in the selector that the recognizer calls. Override `didAddSubview` in the view to which you add subviews on tapping the recognizer, and re-enable it from there. The recognizer will remain inactive through the time while the new subview is being added. If you animate the addition, you should get a sufficient delay to avoid reacting to double-taps.

Comment: mind giving me some example on how to enable it in didAddSubview?

Comment: @aherlambang your gesture recognizer has a property called `enabled`. Set it to `NO` in the selector, and then back to `YES` in the `didAddSubview`.

Answer (score 0):

You could always use a selector with a delay.

```
- (void)performSelector:(SEL)aSelector withObject:(id)anArgument afterDelay:(NSTimeInterval)delay
```

I would also look into using an NSTimer object.